# Given 2 independent and binomially distributed random variables find $P[X_1 < X_2 ]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Im studying for the Probability exam and there was this exercise i stumbeled upon that i needed some help with!

I found it in the solved exercise section which was solved by my professor.

The exercise goes like this:

Let$X_1$ and $X_2$ be 2 independent and Binomially distributed random variables with different parameters: $X_1\sim Bin(1,1/2)$ and $X_2\sim Bin(2,1/2)$

We have to find $P[X_1 < X_2]$

The professor immediately does this:

$P[X_1 < X_2]$=$P[X_1=0]⋅P[X_2 >0] + P[X_1=1]⋅P[X_2 >1]$

=$\frac 12 ⋅ \frac34+\frac 12⋅\frac14$

The first part i understand why he did what he did but i dont understand the 2nd part. How did he get the values there . Can you help me?

Edit: Im more interested in knowing HOW he did get the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Y \sim \text{Bin}(n, p)$, then $P(Y=k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$ for $0 \le k \le n$.

- This allows you to compute $P(X_1=0)$ and $P(X_1=1)$ directly.
- For the other terms, note that $P(X_2 > 0) = P(X_2=1) + P(X_2=2)$ and $P(X_2 > 1) = P(X_2=2)$.